# Which one do you choose, talk more sense or talk more reasonable?

Tags: phrase-choice

1) Does mom talk more sense than daddy?
2) Does mom talk more reasonable than daddy?

Are they both correct? If so, which one is more common. Thank you!

Comment: Mom may be more reasonable, but if so, she would talk more reasonab*ly*...

Comment: In what context? Unless you are trying to say that *sensible* and *reasonable* are synonyms (they aren't), it is better to ask what the difference is, rather than which is more common. But you can't choose which is better without context.

Answer (score 1):

1. The sentence is correct grammatically; the adjective "more" modifies the noun "sense".
2. This sentence isn't correct. You cannot put the adjective reasonable to modify the verb " talk".  Instead, you should use the adverb "reasonably" to modify the verb as follows:

"Does mom talk more reasonably (comparative adverb) than daddy?"

By the way, I think it's more appropriate to use sensibly instead of reasonably so that the sense of the sentence #2 agrees with that of the sentence #1.

Moreover, you can use a comparative adjective after a linking verb as follows:

Is mom more sensible than daddy?

Comment: In the first sentence,  your explanation is OK only if you are considering *more sense* as a noun phrase. But the meaning is not the same as in example 2. I would stick with *sensibly*.